# making Circle button in phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser

im trying to make a circle button with tap event i used hitArea property from sprite class and using pixi Circle class i did that

```
this.sprite = game.add.sprite(50,50,"cursors");

        this.sprite.anchor.set(0.5,0.5);

        this.sprite.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(50,50,84);

        this.sprite.inputEnabled = true;

        this.sprite.events.onInputDown.add(function(){

            console.log("clicked");
        });

    };
```

it is not working at all
so i tried removing  `this.sprite.anchor.set(0.5,0.5);`

input is work fine when there is no hit Area so what should i do

note :
phaser version is 2.2.2

Comment: Use phaser.Circle instead of PIXI.Circle and see if it works, as i know phaser uses pixi as renderer but all namespaces do not begin with PIXI. As you will see if you use PIXI sepertatly

Comment: it is not working too

Comment: this is an example of drawing a Circle in Phaser Examples 

http://phaser.io/examples/v2/display/circle

Comment: this may help you 
http://phaser.io/examples/v2/debug/debug-draw